# What is an effect system?

Tags: programming-languages

I read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_system), but I found it quite abstract. How can an effect system help me as a programmer?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote folks. I'm not sure why I got them other than I'm stupid for some reason? Anyways, appreciate if you can clarify why.

Comment: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: Have an upvote to make up for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An effect system is for [side-effect](/questions/tagged/side-effect)s what a [type-system](/questions/tagged/type-system) is for [type](/questions/tagged/type)s.

An effect system tracks effects of subroutines, classifies subroutines into effect-free and effectful (and possibly what kind of effects a subroutine has), tracks effects across subroutine calls etc.

The vast majority of languages don't care about effects. Some languages, like [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) or [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl/) model effects as types. However, tracking effects separately from types is also a possibility. [java](/questions/tagged/java) has a (very restricted) simple effects system: exceptions are side-effects, and Java has *checked exceptions*, which are an extension of the types of [methods](/questions/tagged/methods). In research, effect systems have been employed to do such things as ensure correct locking of data structures in concurrent programs, for example.

It makes sense (or not sense) to track effects for the same reasons that it makes sense (or not sense) to track types – indeed, functional programmers would say that effects should be part of the type anyway: robustness, safety, documentation, correctness, maintainability, optimization, etc.

Comment: Interesting read